# How to install packages with no internet on Fedora 29?

Tags: networking, fedora, wifi, system-installation, repository

I have a CHUWI Lapbook 15 which I want to install Fedora on. I will often start installation of Fedora with the server spin as it is minimal and doesn't need to first boot into a live cd.

The problem I have is that there is no ethernet port and the packages necessary for accessing wireless networks is not installed with the default setup.

I can confirm that wireless does work when booted into the Fedora Workstation Live CD, however it does not detect the WiFi adapter during the graphical setup from the Fedora Server installer.

How can I go about getting the packages I need to enable wireless networking without an Ethernet port to fall back on and no access to networking during installation?

Comment: Download the [DVD ISO](https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/29/Server/x86_64/iso/Fedora-Server-dvd-x86_64-29-1.2.iso) on a machine that does have internet, mount it on the machine with no internet and use it as the `dnf` package repository.

Comment: How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `--downloadonly` option for yum to download the packages you need to install on another machine or with the live CD. You can use the `--downloaddir` option to specify the folder to save the packages.

```
yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=/home/<username>/Dowloads <package-to-install>
```

Transfer the downloaded `*.rpm` packages to the machine where you want to install it via USB or else.

You can now use `rpm` to install the transferred packages.

```
rpm -ih <package>.rpm
```

You can also use a wildcard to install all copied packages at the same time:

```
rpm -ih *.rpm
```